# SharePoint Online - audience targeting - group id

Tags: sharepoint, spfx, audience

Where / how can I find the id from OData__ModernAudienceTargetUserFieldId or _ModernAudienceTargetUserFieldStringId - the displayed id is not identifiable with groups from await graph.groups();

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqpwY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be from the user information list in the site.

You could find the id from there, the url is : `/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0`

Comment: ok i can see this group (with identifiers), first step - ok BUT how can I get this date via REST?
_api/web/sitesgroups dosn't show these "hidden" groups

Comment: Then end point should be this: /_api/web/siteusers

Comment: I have already found it, but thanks for your help anyway - MembershipGroupId=0 was key :)

Comment: If my answer helps you, please accept it :)